# Cant get basic Python script to work

Tags: python

this is my first time trying to get a Python script to work and not having much luck.

I have a file called 'alpha_script.py' with the following in:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

print "the script is running now"
```

that is in the /bin folder of a project.

Then I run this in terminal

```
chmod +x alpha_script.py
```

nothing happens after I hit enter though, not sure if thats correct or not.
I can run the file just fine with a normal Python command but when I enter this in the terminal

```
./alpha_script.py
```

it returns this error message

```
./alpha_script.py: line 4: print: command not found
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure it's running as python and not as your shell?  Try running it as "python alpha_script.py".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in your shebang line -

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
^ Notice the extra space.
```

The extra space at the starting of the line is causing the issue (That shebang line is not getting picked up correctly) , remove that space and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

There are roughly four things to check here.

1. Is the `#!/usr/bin/env python` literally at the very beginning of your file?  Are there any "hidden" or whitespace characters preceding the the **#!**?
2. Do you actually have the `/usr/bin/env` utility present and executable? (You almost certainly do, it's standard in Linux and other forms of UNIX.  But check anyway).
3. Do you have 'python' on your path, under exactly that name?
4. What version of Python do you have installed as `python`?

I suspect that you just have some space or something in front of your "shebang" (#!) marker.  This will cause some shells to treat the entire file as a shell script and would give the error message that you're getting.

However, the broader lesson to learn is that every on of these things I've enumerated is imported to getting any sort of script running for any scripting language.  You must have a valid "shebang" line (meaning that #! must be the very first characters of the script) ... the path after the #! must be valid ... if you're using `env` then the interpreter named after the space must be valid and on the path ... and lastly that Python changed from versions 2.x (and earlier) to the new 3.x (*print* is no longer a statement ... it's now a function and must be rendered as *print()* with the parentheses around its arguments).

Comment: thank you, it was the spacing issue but good to know about those other things too